# How to process spark JavaRDD data with apache beam?

Tags: apache-beam

I want to process the data from spark JavaRDD Object that I am retrieving from sparksession.sql(" query ") with Apache beam. But I am not able to apply PTransform to this Dataset directly.
I am using Apache Beam 2.14.0(Upgraded Spark runner to use spark version 2.4.3. (BEAM-7265)). Please guide me for this.

```
    SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("test 2.0").master("local[*]").getOrCreate();
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(session.sparkContext());
    final SparkContextOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.as(SparkContextOptions.class);
    options.setRunner(SparkRunner.class);
    options.setUsesProvidedSparkContext(true);
    options.setProvidedSparkContext(jsc);
    options.setEnableSparkMetricSinks(false);

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    List<StructField> srcfields  = new ArrayList<StructField>();
    srcfields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("dataId", DataTypes.IntegerType, true));
    srcfields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("code", DataTypes.StringType, true));
    srcfields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("value", DataTypes.StringType, true));
    srcfields.add(DataTypes.createStructField("dataFamilyId", DataTypes.IntegerType, true));
    StructType dataschema = DataTypes.createStructType(srcfields);
    List<Row> dataList = new ArrayList<Row>();
    dataList.add(RowFactory.create(1, "AA", "Apple", 1));
    dataList.add(RowFactory.create(2, "AB", "Orange", 1));
    dataList.add(RowFactory.create(3, "AC", "Banana", 2));
    dataList.add(RowFactory.create(4, "AD", "Guava", 3));
    Dataset<Row> rawData = new SQLContext(jsc).createDataFrame(dataList, dataschema);//pipeline.getOptions().getRunner().cast();  
    JavaRDD<Row> javadata = rawData.toJavaRDD();

    System.out.println("***************************************************");
    for(Row line:javadata.collect()){
        System.out.println(line.getInt(0)+"\t"+line.getString(1)+"\t"+line.getString(2)+"\t"+line.getInt(3));
    }
    System.out.println("***************************************************");

    pipeline.apply(Create.of(javadata))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<JavaRDD<Row>,String> ()
    {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
            JavaRDD<Row> row = c.element();
            c.output("------------------------------");
            System.out.println(".............................");

        }
    }
            ))
    .apply("WriteCounts", TextIO.write().to("E:\\output\\out"));

    final PipelineResult result = pipeline.run();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("***********************************end");
```

Answer (score 2):

I don’t believe it’s possible since Beam is supposed to know nothing about Spark RDDs and Beam Spark Runner hides all Spark-related things under the hood. Potentially, you can create custom Spark specific `PTransform`, which will read from RDD, and use it as input of your pipeline for your specific cases but I'm not sure it's a good idea and, perhaps, it can be solved in other way. Could you share more details about your data processing pipeline?

Comment: Thanks Alexey, I want to process the Hive data from org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset Object that I am retrieving from sparksession.sql("select * from employee") with Apache beam. But I am not able to apply PTransform to this Dataset directly. Right now I am using a solution in which I dump the Dataset to csv file using SparkSession and then process it with Apache Beam. Is there any way in which I can consume Dataset / JavaRDD directly into the beam (Ptransform)?

Please guide me for this.

Comment: As @ibzib mentioned before, there is no way to apply `PTransform` over Dataset/RDD directly. Also, it's not possible to use SparkSQL directly too since it's not portable for other data processing engine. In the same time, you can try to use BeamSQL instead: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/overview/
For example, you can dump your data into Avro format files and then process it with AvroIO and BeamSQL further.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly consume Spark Datasets or RDDs into Beam, but you should be able to ingest data from Hive into a Beam PCollection instead. See the docs for Beam's HCatalog IO connector: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/hcatalog/

Comment: But HCatalog IO supports Hive DDL SQL Query. I need DML SQL and Complex query(Join,Group by,row_number() over (partition by gender order by gender) as row_num etc). SparkSQL provides this type of functionality, how to achieve this in apache beam HCatalogIO.